# Need help figuring why G isn't defined in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

```
import networkx as nx
A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
A.add_edge(0,1)
A.add_edge(0,2)
A.add_edge(1,2)
A.add_edge(2,3)
A.add_edge(2,4)
A.add_edge(3,4)
x = 0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print(i,j, A(i))
    x+=A(i,j)
print(x)
```

I'm trying to write a For loop that prints all the values of the elements of the matrix created by the network mentioned above. In addition, is there a way to add a function that counts the degrees of each nodes and prints them out in the i, j format?

Comment: You never defined `G`. You need first to create a empty graph `G` (`G = nx.Graph()`), a random graph (`nx.random_graphs.erdos_renyi_graph()`) or load some `G`

Answer (score -1):

`G` is a `Graph` object that's supposed to be passed to the `ns.adjacency_matrix()` function. (You don't *have* to call it `G`; that's just the name that `adjacency_matrix()` uses inside itself.) But if you're happy with `G`, then add the following line after your `import` line: `G = nx.Graph()`, and change all of the `A.add_edge()` calls to `G.add_edge()` (since `add_edge()` is a `Graph` function, not an adjacency matrix one.